# How to get data from logfile to insert on gtk list store / tree view?

Tags: c, treeview, gtk, logfile

Using Gtk+2 and Glade 3.8.5 I've created a treeview and I'm using a liststore as model, but I want to make the treeview to get data from a logfile (as .txt file) or SQLite database, but it would be actually better to get it from a logfile. I'm programming in **C** and I really hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved my problem by using fgets, I kinda feel dumb that I've posted this question now.

```
 char dhd_getbuf[1024];
 FILE * dhd_pFile;

  dhd_pFile = fopen ("Logs/logCancelar.txt", "r");

    while( (fgets(dhd_getbuf, sizeof(dhd_getbuf), dhd_pFile))!=NULL ) {
    ...
  }
```

That worked fine.